# What are the advantages/disadvantages of Cocoa frameworks, libraries, and bundles?

Tags: macos, frameworks, bundle

I have the following requirement.

I need to implement dll kind of thing on mac.I need to create a backend library which can be loaded dynamically.This backend library will contain the cocoa classes and c++ classes.

What is advantage/disadvantage of cocoa framework,I was googling so far,I was not able to figure out the best one.Please give me some suggestion.Is cocoa framework also loaded dynamically?

Comment: What is advantage/disadvantage of cocoa framework comparing with library/bundle?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main difference between a dynamic library and a framework is that a framework can contain resources (images, sound files, nibs, etcetera) and header files. When you use a dynamic library, these are separate.

Both a framework and a dynamic library are loaded at runtime. If your library will only be used on Mac OS X, I recommend creating a framework because it is easier to manage since everything is in one folder.

Bundles (the white LEGO bricks) are almost exclusively used as plug-ins. If you want to create a plug-in interface you should accept bundles and you should provide a framework the bundles can link against. Bundles are also loaded at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,again got confused,how plugin differentiate from library.

Comment: An application may depend on dynamic libraries and frameworks, while plug-ins are optional. Plug-ins can be created by third parties to add extra functionality to your application. Of course it's not a requirement to provide a plug-in interface.

Comment: Yeh got it,Thanks again.As you said frameworks are also loaded dynamically.While creation cocoa frameworks,We will build the framework project and copy to /Library/Framework.While using this in our application ,we need to add the framework to our project that means we are statically linking the framework at compile time.How it can be said loading runtime.please clease this.

Comment: Frameworks are always linked dynamically. They are loaded *just before* the program runs.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [decent tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/cocoatutorials/downloads/detail?name=console.pdf) (PDF form) that goes a little more in depth explaining the differences between ordinary libraries and frameworks.